# How to tell ipcluster which python.exe to start

Tags: python, parallel-processing, ipython

I have python2,7_32bit  "classically" installed on my Windows 7. It is integrated in registry, so when I double click a .py file, it is executed with this python...

But since a long time, I use a portable installation of Winpython with python3,5_64bit (which I recommend, btw).

Last week, I executed this command in DOS console :

```
"C:\\Program Files\\WinPython-64bit-3.5.1.1\\python-3.5.1.amd64\\scripts\\ipcluster" start -n 4 --profile-dir="cluster"
```

it worked as expected, and started 4 python64bit_3,5 processes.

Now, the same ipcluster command starts python32bit instances from the "installed" version. (I see 32bit in the Windows Task Manager, and I can right-click "open location file" to be sure which python.exe is executed by the process)

Of course, it produces compatibility problems (valueError unsupported pickle protocol 3) between Python 2 and 3.

So the short term solution is to uninstall my old python, but I would like to have a good solution because this program should run on other computer which might also have different Python installed.

I guess there is something to write in a "ipcluster_config.py" but I can't find any example nor documentation for a "local" engine.
For example, this is for a SSH engine : https://github.com/ipython/ipyparallel/pull/10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to call ipcluster from the python.exe you need :

this command :

```
WinPython-64bit-3.5.1.2\python-3.5.1.amd64\python.exe "WinPython-64bit-3.5.1.1\python-3.5.1.amd64\Scripts\ipcluster.exe" start -n 4
```

gave me processes from the python 3.5.1.2.... (and not 3.5.1.1)

it is actually the way it is meant to work, I guess... (and it is now clear why I got the old version, but not how it could have worked before)